# Java Threading Issue with run()

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 2 classes defined below:

```
public class TextsManager extends Thread {
    LinkedList<String> lstOfPendingStr = new LinkedList<String>();

    boolean stopLoop = false;

    JTextArea txtArea;
    public void run()
    {
        while (!stopLoop)
        {               
            while (!lstOfPendingStr.isEmpty())
            {               
                String tmp = lstOfPendingStr.getFirst();
                this.txtArea.append(tmp);                   
                lstOfPendingStr.removeFirst();              
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(0);    //  note: I had to force this code
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
        }       
    }

    public void AddNewStr(String newStr)
    {       
        this.lstOfPendingStr.add(newStr);   
    }   

}
```

And

```
public class ClientApp {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    static private TextsManager txtManager;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ClientApp window = new ClientApp();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);                  
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               
            }
        });     
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public ClientApp() {
        initialize();

        /*
         * Client app
         */
        txtManager =  new TextsManager(textArea);

        txtManager.start();     
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();

        textArea = new JTextArea(); 

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                {
                    txtManager.AddNewStr(textField.getText() + "\n");
                    textField.setText("");
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

The program will read User Input from `textField`, pass it into `TextsManager.lstOfPendingStr`. Then, on each loop inside `TextsManager.run`(), it will check for existed members in `lstOfPendingStr` and output them via `txtArea`.

The problem is that if I removed the code `Thread.sleep(0)` inside `run()`, the `run()` then apparently stopped working. Despite `lstOfPendingStr` had been successfully updated with new elements, codes inside the loop `while(!lstOfPendingStr.isEmpty())` would not ever to be called.

I put hard codes such as `System.out.println` or `Thread.sleep(0)` (as in the provided code) inside the `while(!stopLoop)`, then it worked fine.

Although, I managed to solve the problem by forcing the thread to sleep for a few miliseconds, I want to know the reason behind this issue.

I appreciate your wisdom.

Regard :)

Comment: Your example does not compile as you posted it and it generally looks a bit too big. Please make it smaller.A wild guess would be that the updates are not seen in the thread that tries to read from the list while the other one is adding them. You might want to try using a collection that works well with multiple threads (see java.util.concurrent). I am quite unsure about the semantics of Thread.sleep, but this might cause the memory to be synchronized, which is why your code works once you add that.

Comment: After getting rid of compilation errors in your code and getting it to run, I get the expected output even if I remove the `Thread.sleep(0)` section. Even after removing this section, when I type something in JTextField and press enter, it gets shown in JTextArea

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72035476/srcCode.zip

Here is my completed srcCode and an executable build in which I excluded the Thread.sleep(0).

By the way, the code worked fine in debugging mode. It's the released build which is encountering this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of problems.

1. You are calling methods on `lstOfPendingStr` from two threads, but initialized it with `LinkedList`, which is not thread-safe. You should use a thread safe class, `LinkedBlockingQueue` seems the best options as far as I understood from your code.
2. Inside the thread you are calling `JTextArea#append()`. As all AWT/Swing methods, you can not call them from arbitrary threads, but only from the AWT thread. Wrap the call inside an `invokeLater` block.

The fact that `sleep` appears to make your code work is just a sign of the concurrency problems.